# How do I import a @Configuration annotated Spring context configuration file in Grails?

Tags: spring, grails, spring-java-config

In Grails 3, how do I reuse a Spring context configuration class (annotated with @Configuration, @Bean, @Value annotations) from a dependency jar, so that all the defined beans and values are properly set up?

Cheers,
Kai